# File separator constant displays false separator?

Tags: java, file, file-io

i am creating a method 'newOutputPath()' that copies an existing path but it changes the name in the provided path. for an example if i have a path c:/../parentDir/img.ext, this method copies the same path but change the name of the file to somthing like:
c:/../parentDir/AutoGen_img.ext

but when i call

```
    System.out.println(FilePathUtils.newOutputPath());
```

it returns 'please note the \ character:

```
    C:/private/ArbeitsOrdner_19_Mar_2015/Images/FeaturesDetection/samples_00\AutoGenPath_queryjpg
```

as you see in the code i am using File.separator, why it is causing this false separator '\' i expected '/' instead?

**code**:

```
        // i always add the first object but it's not must, we can choose any valid index or choose any valid index randomly.
                                    FilePathUtils.outputFilePathToParentDirList.add(FilePathUtils.getInputFilePathToParentDirList().get(0));
                                    Log.D(TAG, "newOutputPath", FilePathUtils.outputFilePathToParentDirList.get(0));

                                    FilePathUtils.outputFilePathExtList.add(FilePathUtils.getInputFilePathExtList().get(0));
                                    Log.D(TAG, "newOutputPath", FilePathUtils.outputFilePathExtList.get(0)); // prints C:/private/ArbeitsOrdner_19_Mar_2015/Images/FeaturesDetection/samples_00

                                    FilePathUtils.outputImageNameList.add(SystemConstants.AUTO_GEN_PREFIX + FilePathUtils.getInputImageNameList().get(0));
                                    Log.D(TAG, "newOutputPath", FilePathUtils.outputImageNameList.get(0)); //prints jpg

                                    FilePathUtils.outputFileFullPathList.add(FilePathUtils.outputFilePathToParentDirList.get(0) + File.separator + 
                                    FilePathUtils.outputImageNameList.get(0) + FilePathUtils.outputFilePathExtList.get(0)); // prints AutoGenPath_query

                                    if (FilePathUtils.getOutpathFileFullPathListSize() != -1) {
                                        if (FilePathUtils.getOutpathFileFullPathListSize() == 0) 
                                            return FilePathUtils.outputFileFullPathList.get(0);
                                            return FilePathUtils.outputFileFullPathList.get(FilePathUtils.getOutpathFileFullPathListSize() -1 );

                                    } else {
                                        Log.WTF(TAG, "newOutputPath", "outputFileFullPathList is null 'un-initialised at this far of the checking'");
                                        return null;
                                    }


        /**
        * This method is to return the size of the outputFileFullPathList list.
        * @return
        * the size of the outputFileFullPathList, or -1 if the outputFileFullPathList list is null "un-initialised" or 0 if it is empty.
        */
        public static int getOutpathFileFullPathListSize() {
            if (FilePathUtils.outputFileFullPathList != null) {

            if (!FilePathUtils.outputFileFullPathList.isEmpty()) {
                return FilePathUtils.outputFileFullPathList.size();
            } else {
                Log.D(TAG, "getOutpathFileFullPathListSize", "outputFileFullPathList list is empty");
                return 0;
        }

        } else {
            Log.E(TAG, "getOutpathFileFullPathListSize", "outputFileFullPathList list is null because it was not initilised, call StorePath method first to initlise it.");
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

**outPut**:

```
Debug: FilePathUtils -> newOutputPath: C:/private/ArbeitsOrdner_19_Mar_2015/Images/FeaturesDetection/samples_00
Debug: FilePathUtils -> newOutputPath: jpg
Debug: FilePathUtils -> newOutputPath: AutoGenPath_query
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the file separator on Windows *is* `\` rather than `/`. Windows will accept either in many situations but officially the separator is backslash so that's what Java on Windows uses for `File.separator`.

Comment: so do you mean that the output is correct and the path is valid? please inform

Comment: Indeed, but you are mixing slashes. Instead, as he said, you should use File.separator, which it is OS agnostic.

Comment: @user2121 how did you produce the orginal paths? And yes, what you get is valid.

Comment: @Johnny i declared them as final and i hard-coded this separator  "/"

Comment: @Johnny is there any system constant for the dot preceeds the extension, as in 'file.extension' for an example?

Comment: @user2121 the use of dots is not platform dependent so there's no need for a constant to represent it.  It's simply a character in the file's name, not a separator between different things.